# How to use pure FP (ramda or similar) to solve practical plasma cutting

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js, enumerable

I have a very practical problem of generating plasma cutting line in a pattern. See attached image

I feel this would be a good demo of pure functional programming techniques, if somebody is willing to share solution using ramda or similar lib, as I'm trying to learn solving problems in FP way but honestly here I don't even know where to start

```
// arrays a and b will always have same size, but number of points vary from cut to cut

let a = ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']    
let b = ['B0','B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5']

// need to make array c combining the two arrays in the following pattern
c = ['A0', 'A1', 'B1', 'B2', 'A2', 'A3','B3', 'B4', 'A4', 'A5' ...]
```

[image: Plasma Cutting Line]

Comment: As a start: `zipWith(concat, chunksOf(2, lineA), chunksOf(2, tail(lineB)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Bergi's lead I learned a lot about FP today.
Using ramda I got it working

```
let a = ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']    
let b = ['B0','B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5']
let c = flatten(zipWith(concat, splitEvery(2, a), splitEvery(2, tail(b))))
```